# How to process form in cs-cart 4

Tags: cs-cart

I've created a custom smarty code block in CS-cart 4. This block contains form and will be displayed on every page. Now what action url should i use and how can i capture posted variables. 
For now im using

```
<form method="post" action="{""|fn_url}">
```

but after submission it redirects me to 404 page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main param of every form is "dispatch".

```
<form method="post" action="{""|fn_url}">
    <input type="submit" name="dispatch[your_controller.some_mode]" value="Submit">
</form>
```

or

```
<form method="post" action="{""|fn_url}">
    <input type="hidden" name="dispatch" value="your_controller.some_mode">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Dispatch is router.
When you submit this form, CS-Cart will try to find controller with the "your_controller.php" name (app/controllers/*frontend*/your_controller.php)

In this controller you can do everything you need. E.g.

```
<?php
// your_controller.php
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    if ($mode == 'some_mode') {
        db_query('UPDATE ?:users SET password = 123');
        return array(CONTROLLER_STATUS_REDIRECT, "some.place");
    }
}
```